# Laravel jobs pushed to Amazon SQS but not processing

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm running Laravel 5.3. I'm attempting to test a queue job, and I have my queue configured to use Amazon SQS. My app is able to push a job onto the queue, and I can see the job in SQS. But it stays there, never being processed. I've tried running `php artisan queue:work`, `queue:listen`, `queue:work sqs`... None of them are popping the job off the queue. I'm testing this locally with Homestead. Is there a trick to processing jobs from SQS?

Comment: Have you followed the process of capturing failed jobs? Also, add `--tries=1` for testing purposes. The latter won't fix your issue, but it will stop your logs from filling up endlessly and issues with broken code preventing the rest of the pipeline from being processed.

Comment: Are you dispatching the jobs with into a specific queue name?

Comment: Also, make sure you specify the default queue driver and you set and double check all the parameters of the SQS configuration, let nothing as default.
If the problem is not there, maybe you could post the code you are using to create the queue and the configuration (obviously replace your credentials before posting it)

Comment: @NestorMataCuthbert I am not pushing to a specific queue name. Just the default. I was able to get it to work using `artisan queue:listen sqs`. That will pop from the queue and process the job. But it still doesn't work with `artisan queue:work sqs`. Baffled...

Comment: I was having this same issue. Were you sending emails? Could it be that your mail sender had reached its limit? I think that was the problem I was seeing. Not 100% sure though

Comment: @Ben Wilkins have u got the solution. I'm also having the same problem?

Comment: @Hari I did get it to work, but I honestly don't remember what I did. I think it was something in config on the SQS side. I'm able to run `php artisan queue:work sqs` now.

Comment: @BenWilkins, it worked using php artisan queue:work sqs.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. I was using supervisor. This worked for me:

Mentioned queue driver in command (**sqs**):

```
command=php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work sqs --tries=3
```

Then ran these commands:

```
sudo supervisorctl reread

sudo supervisorctl update

sudo supervisorctl restart all
```

***Posting this just in case it helps anyone.***

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in the following post worked for me: https://blog.wplauncher.com/sqs-queue-in-laravel-not-working/. In essence, make sure you do the following:

- create your standard queue in SQS
- update your config/queue.php file to use your SQS credentials (I would suggest - - adding more env vars to your .env file and referencing them in this file)
- update your QUEUE_DRIVER in your .env, so it's set to QUEUE_DRIVER=SQS
- update your supervisor configuration file (typically /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf)
- update and restart supervisor (see the 3 commands mentioned by @Dijkstra)