# Amazon SQS "Receive Count" only increasing

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I'm new to Amazon SQS, but some of the figures are alarming so far.

I've configured Laravel to queue email messages (not using a job, but just by extending a notification class, [as per the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#queueing-notifications)) which are being sent by my site using Amazon SQS. The service itself seems to work fine. All the messages appear in the SQS queue of my AWS account, but the problem is that the queue just seems to be huge.

I can't find any decent tutorials or guides that explain how to read the SQS screen written in plain English, so everything MAY be fine. That said, I'd like to make sure.

Consider what SQS is currently saying:

> Messages available: 300
>   Messages in Flight: 4
>   Messages delayed: 0

When I tested it when it first went live, the emails were being sent immediately. The "Messages available" was empty, and the emails arrived in my inbox without issue.

Today the figure is considerably higher, as you can see, and it never seems to fully reach 0. In addition to this the emails are taking several hours to arrive.

Is this normal?

I've SSH'd into my Elastic Beanstalk instance and taken a look around.  I've manually added five background processes running `php artisan queue:work`, each consumes ~5% of the CPU. Hmm.

If I manually run the same command (without `nohup`) I see a constantly updating list:

> [2018-04-04 20:09:59] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll
>   [2018-04-04 20:09:59] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionVIP
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:00] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionVIP
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:00] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionVIP
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:00] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:00] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:00] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:02] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:02] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:02] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:02] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:02] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:02] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:03] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:03] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:03] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:03] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll
>   [2018-04-04 20:10:03] Processing: App\Notifications\CompetitionAll

Only every so often does one change to Processed, most of the time it's an endless list of yellow Processing, changing every second.

When I view the messages in SQS, I see very high "Receive counts". Some as high as **21,000+**!

[image]

I know that there's probably only been about 2000 email requests in total, so I don't understand how this count could get so high.

Is this normal? It seems as though Laravel isn't deleting completed requests. (Plus it seems almost impossible to find an explanation of these numbers...!)

Any help understand what's going on would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post your `.env` file and job file? It looks like the mail is queued but the job is not dispatched correctly.

Comment: Those are very high receive counts. That typically represents some error during processing, so the message just goes back into the queue. It's also possible the message visibility timeout is much lower than the time it takes to process a message

Comment: @parthu_panther The .env file is obviously correct as the messages are appearing in SQS. I don't have a job file, I'm just using a notification class, as per the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#queueing-notifications

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519581/laravel-jobs-pushed-to-amazon-sqs-but-not-processing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Ugh. It seems the problem was just a silly gotcha:

Our email delivery provider hit their daily limit.

Once we'd increased our limited, the queue cleared in minutes.

I'll leave this question here incase it helps anyone else.

Comment: nice answer, cracked me up

Comment: Hey thanks for answering this. Can you clear up on thing though? Is receive count the amount of times the queue has gotten that exact same message payload? Does this mean in your case this message could have failed 21,426 times?

Comment: @Stewart, that means the number of times the message was "received" by the client, becoming "invisible", then the visibility timeout expired, turning the message available again.